# Get filename of file which is about to upload - PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the filename of a file I´m about to upload and I´m trying it with this code:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

But sadly I get back "Array". Can someone please explain me why?

```
array(1) {
    ["file"]=> array(5) {
        ["name"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> string(12) "download.jpg"
        }
        ["type"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
        }
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> string(38) "/home/.sites/60/site1048/tmp/phpj38Yhn"
        }
        ["error"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> int(0)
        }
        ["size"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> int(12494)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the result of `var_dump($_FILES);` please.

Comment: array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "download.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(38) "/home/.sites/60/site1048/tmp/phpj38Yhn" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(12494) } } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][0];